# How to open a file .svg in the app in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android

How to add a file with the extension svg and be able to change and edit all its items?
I mean, I want to add a svg in Java code and make changes to it.

Comment: Nice. Something unique. But, I don't think we can edit and display a svg in android. We can surely display it using [this](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp) library and maybe modify also. But, it is not possible in way like path data and those things